# Best Approach Switching Between Prod and Dev Configurations in Git

Tags: git, configuration-files, production

We are using Git and as usual, our work flow is development > staging > production.

The project has several config files. During development, configs point to development databases. However, after changes in development and I'm ready to deploy, the configs will need to change and point to production databases.

During the next round of changes, I will need to change configs again to point to development databases.

This cycle then keeps repeating itself, and it's tedious since I have 3 config files (best I can do is 2, since one config file is for a particular library).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you absolutely must keep the configuration files in the repository, have you considered using branches for this? Create production branch from development, make changes to the config file to match production and off you go. You would then merge development into production at various points which should keep the configuration file you modified, until you get a merge conflict at least.

Comment: The normal advice is to only store templates in the repository and have a build step or similar that detects that the real configuration file is missing on disk and then make a copy from the template. You would then edit the config file on disk. This would not allow you to automagically check out production ready configuration files, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LasseV.Karlsen I added config files in .gitignore, but they were still not 'ignored', haven't yet figured out why. Tried untracking, and my config files were gone!

I did create a production branch, into which I merge development branch every time and it's working. 

I'm really interested in using templates to create config during build step. I will need to work on my build which is way too basic.

Comment: Yes, you will have problems since you already added the config files to your repository. There is no way to tell git "please stop tracking these files but leave them on disk when checking out". You must handle the crossover from "bad config management" to "proper config management" by ensuring you still have config files on disk after you've checked out the new commit. Make a copy of the config files and restore them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your config file contains database information such as host, username, password...

IMO a good way to get around that is to store database information into environment variables, and get them into your config file(s).

For instance, in development, staging and production, the database host would be stored in an environment variable named `DATABASE_HOST`. In the config file you'd have this line (`php` code)

```
 $databaseHost = getenv('DATABASE_HOST');
 // ...
```

And as @Lasse V. Karlsen said, a template should be tracked by git and the config file itself should be git-ignored. 
This way, the developers don't have to create environment variables, and they have to do is to create the config file (git-ignored of course) from the template and set their database information (and why not other information that depends on the server, environment ...)

So to sum up, configuration file should be get-ignored, a template should be created instead. When deploying, configuration file is created from the template.
The new configuration file gets the wanted environment variables.
Developers, however, can create these environment variables in local or modify values of their configuration file.

Comment: Thanks @smarber, I'm gettting the concept, I'm not sure it will work for .properties type of files. Probably a dumb question but where exactly are environment variables stored?

Comment: Or you mean environment variables set in the system?

Comment: @SamuelWaithaka yes I meant you should set environment variables that you get from your configuration files somehow (I think all languages allows that)